# Meteor JS not working behind a proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze, angular-meteor

I am facing trouble running a meteor app using it behind proxy. I am trying to run a meteor app using the following commands -

cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local.meteor\myapp1>
meteor

Before going to the meteor directory I am also setting the proxy like this -

SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username: password:pwd

SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://username: password:pwd

meteor update

But this doesn`t seem to work and shows the following message -

[image: Message]

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with being behind a proxy.  It means your shell does not understand what the `meteor` command is.

Make sure meteor has been added to your PATH and if not, add it manually.

On Windows 10

1. Right click on Start Menu and select 'System'
2. On the left, click 'Advanced system settings'
3. Click 'Environment Variables...'
4. At the top, scroll down to 'PATH' and click 'Edit'

Make sure you see `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor` in there and if not, add it!

Also, I would advise you keep your Meteor projects in an easier to remember place (e.g. not in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor`).  Perhaps somewhere inside your Users folder?

On a side note, your approach for dealing with the proxy is correct (e.g. setting `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`).  It should work once you fix your other issue.